# В терминале мак после вывода пишет знак %

Tags: c++, консоль, macos

При выводе в терминале через cout постоянно выводит знак %. Я так понял, что он ждет дальнейшего ввода, но как это убрать? Помогает после cout писать endl или "\n", но это не очень удобно и в некоторых ситуациях невозможно. Вроде бы раньше такого не было.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выполняйте вашу программу как `./app; echo` =)

Comment: И просто печатайте в конце перенос строки.

Answer (score 1):

это так шелл (думаю, это все таки zsh) или терминал показывает Вам, что вывод предыдущей команды завершился без перевода строки.

вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977990/why-zsh-adds-at-the-end-of-my-output)

Там предлагают исправить здесь

iTerm 2: Preferences->Profiles->Terminal->Report Terminal Type.

у меня мака нет, проверить не могу

Comment: Прочитал, так и не понял что нужно исправить или поменять. Единственное похожее на то что описывалось в iTerm 2 я нашел TermInfo (скрин добавил к описанию вопроса), но там у меня и так стоит xterm-256color. О нем вроде бы и было написано.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметил @KoVadim это ваш шелл, zsh, отмечает, что добавил перевод строки к выводу программы. Данная функция управляется переменной окружения PROMPT_EOL_MARK, если не установлена - реверсивный процент.

```
leo@leom20 ~ % printf "No LF"
No LF%
leo@leom20 ~ % PROMPT_EOL_MARK="{XXX"
leo@leom20 ~ % printf "No LF"
No LF{XXX
leo@leom20 ~ % PROMPT_EOL_MARK=""
leo@leom20 ~ % printf "No LF"
No LF
leo@leom20 ~ %
```

Её можно установить в profile, а можно в настройках шелл терминальной программы. `man zsh`, `man zshoptions`, ... - полезное чтение.

P.S.
Да, раньше по-умолчанию был bash, у него другие тараканы, но можно к нему вернуться...